# Velocity needed to take a particle from point A to B in X seconds

Tags: kinematics

I have been trying to find an equation to fit this problem for a bit now, and I'm not sure where else to turn to.

I am trying to move a particle in 3D space from point A to point B, in X seconds with g gravity. I have been looking for an equation that when I plug these variables in, I can get the velocity that when applied, will create an arc from the two points.

Here is a demonstration of what I am trying to reproduce: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81AlpUhkOAk

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for “check my work” problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hello, this is not homework a help problem. I am working on a video game, and needed help with this equation. I've been trying to figure this out myself for a long time now, and am still lost, so I came here for help. If this post is not allowed, I will delete it.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a homework problem.

Comment: @jim : The policy applies to "homework and **exercises**." A request for a calculation or method of calculation is an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a coordinate system with *y*-axis "up" (against gravity) and *x*-axis along the line connecting *A* and *B*.

To span the horizontal distance $x_B-x_A$ in given time $\Delta t$ the horizontal speed should be $$v_x = \frac{x_B-x_A}{\Delta t}$$

So the equation for the *x* coordinate is $\boxed{x(t) = x_A + v_x t}$.

Similarly to go from *A* to *B* in the vertical direction you have

$$\left. y_B - y_A = v_y \Delta t - \frac{1}{2} g \Delta t^2 \right\} \; v_y = \frac{y_B-y_A}{\Delta t} + \frac{1}{2} g \Delta t$$

So the equation for the *y* coordinate is $\boxed{y(t) = y_A + v_y t - \frac{1}{2} g t^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can assume a coordinate system such that the origin is at A, the starting point, and the problem is to determine the speed and direction of the projectile so that it reaches the point B in a time $X$. By rotating the axes you can make the further assumption that the point B lies in, say, the $xz$ plane. This means that you have to deal with the problem shown in the figure (where the point B is down range by R and height h above the ground
[image]

The distance travelled in the $x$ direction after a time $X$ is $x = v\cos \theta X$, while the distance travelled in the $z$ direction after the same time $X$ is given as $z = v \sin \theta X - \frac{1}{2}gX^2$, since motion in the $z$ direction is influenced by gravity (the minus sign reflects that the projectile is moving upwards). All you have to do is put $x = R, z = h$ and you can find $R = v \cos \theta X$, $h+\frac{1}{2}gX^2 = v \sin \theta X$. Dividing these two gives $\frac{v \sin \theta X}{v \cos \theta X}=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \tan \theta = \frac{R}{h + \frac{1}{2}gX^2}$. With $\theta$ determined you can find $v$, though it is also determined from $$v^2 X^2 = R^2 + (h+ \frac{1}{2}gX^2)^2$$.

With $v, \theta$ determined the position of the projectile at time $t$ is $$x(t) = v \cos \theta t, z(t) = v \sin \theta t - \frac{1}{2}g t^2$$ with $0 \lt t \lt X$.

Answer (score 0):

For the overview, here are the four general main kinematic "motion" equations with which you can model anything if just acceleration is constant:

$$x=x_0+v_{x0}t+\frac 12 a_x t^2\\
x=x_0+\frac 12(v_x+v_{x0})t\\
v_x=v_{x0}+a_xt\\
v_x^2=v_{x0}^2+2a(x-x_0)$$

You can always set these up in any direction between any two points, with $0$ being the start-point. Just remember that they work along a path, so for example set up an equation in each axis-direction, and then place your coordinate axes sp that an axis points directly towards the end-point - this will make things easier and you might be able to solve it as a 2D problem.

Note that they each leave out one parameter; so choose the right one(s) that don't bring in to many unknowns. And also note that one equation must only include the parameter-components **in the particular chosen direction** - for example, the first-mentioned equation above would in the $x$ and $y$ directions become:

$$x=x_0+v_0\cos(\alpha)t\\
y=y_0+v_0\sin(\alpha)t-\frac 12 g t^2$$

where $x$ and $y$ would be the coordinates of the end-point, and $\alpha$ would be the angle with which, the object is thrown (so that $v_{x0}=v_0\cos(\alpha)$  would be the component in the $x$ direction).